# Configuation file for hibernate has errors

Tags: hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://cdcvgdc2012t;DatabaseName=SMS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">training</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Tr@!n@n10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


        <mapping resource="com/jwt/hibernate/bean/user.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I got an error that :
Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
error
and this is my config file